# Set app as default button interaction with UI automator

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso, android-uiautomator, android-instrumentation

I have a test case where in the app "Set as default" prompt is opened. I want to test that with UI automator, and I had success with testing that case, but not 100% reliable. Unfortunately, some devices have "Set as default" prompt button written in caps, and some of those don't, so I'm not able to create 100% reliable tests for this test case. I have written this code below, but when fetching "Set as default" button by text, case of the letters don't play a role, but when I want to interact with that button, text case is important. Switching the IF-ELSE cases doesn't fix the problem in this case. And somehow, none of the dialog buttons ids work (button1, button2..) when I want to press those.

```
if (roleManager.isRoleAvailable(android.app.role.ASSISTANT)) {
    if (!roleManager.isRoleHeld(android.app.role.ASSISTANT)) {
        val myApp = device.findObject(UiSelector().textMatches(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext.getString(R.string.app_name)))
        myApp.click()
        sleepLong()
        var setAsDefaultButton: UiObject? = null
        if (device.findObject(UiSelector().text("Set as default")) != null) {
            setAsDefaultButton = device.findObject(UiSelector().text("Set as default"))
            setAsDefaultButton?.click()
        } else if (device.findObject(UiSelector().text("SET AS DEFAULT")) != null) {
            setAsDefaultButton = device.findObject(UiSelector().text("SET AS DEFAULT"))
            setAsDefaultButton?.click()
        } else {
            clickDialogPositiveButton()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [Jordan's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1576621/jordan-junior) example and hint, solution to this is to find an object with the Pattern. With pattern, you can search for UIObject with `By.text(pattern)`. Take a note that the object found with the pattern needs to be `UIObject2` instead of the `UIObject`.

```
val pattern = Pattern.compile("Set as the default", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
if(device.findObject(UiSelector().text(pattern.toString())) != null) {
    device.findObject(By.text(pattern)).click()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Pattern` object instead of using a string.

You can use in your code like:

```
val pattern = Pattern.compile("Set as default", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
val setDefaultText = device.findObject(UiSelector().text(pattern))
if(setDefaultText != null)) {
    setDefaultText.click()
} else {
   clickDialogPositiveButton()
}
```

Comment: Thanks on input, but main issue comes from ```setAsDefaultButton = device.findObject(UiSelector().text("Set as default"))``` line, where text case plays biggest role.

Comment: I don't know what you did on your sleepLong() method, but I think this can be the issue. Try to use the method wait from UiDevice like this: device.wait(Until.findObjects(By.text(pattern)), 1000))

Comment: ```sleepLong()``` is ```Thread.sleep(3000)``` in this case, and it is not relevant. I tried to use this method you suggested without success.
But I managed to resolve this issue with the                       ```device.findObject(By.text(pattern)).click()``` line.
Thank you a lot for the hint, I will post the complete answer!